# Changing blob url to download link

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, blob

I'm trying to make a download link from a Blob Url. I want to add the correct file extension which I have saved in a variable.

Code below doesn't open the link. If I enter the blob url separately it opens the file but of course without the correct extension.

I think the click() might be the problem...but why?

Please help

```
console.debug(objectURL);
//blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/46e5abd5-a0a1-4b9c-97bc-052fb0d41803         

var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);

a.style = "display: none";
a.download = 'myFile' + fileExtension;
a.href = objectURL;

a.click();
```

Comment: Check my example: http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/5KRf6/60/

Comment: Sorry but could you please transform your code to plain Javascript. There is also the difference that your link is not being triggered by 'click()'

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pssLS/ ?